# Play framework SOLID principles

Tags: scala, architecture, playframework

I'm learning Scala/Play2.1.3 from a C#/.Net/ASP.NET MVC background.

I wonder why there is no dependency injection support by default?

In Play samples, all data-access methods are static in the domain model classes. They use factories instead of injections. What if I want to mock some data-access methods for unit-testing?

There is no ready-to-use high-level ORM there. Actually they discourage me to use ORMs! Regarding SQL DBs I can't believe that I have to write joins again which I don't remember the last time I wrote a join clause. Isn't it a step backward?

I've learned to use SOLID principals which are not observed in Play framework (completely) IMO.

Am I wrong your I should consider using another framework?

Comment: It's quite easy to set up DI and get rid of those static controller methods. I think it's good that they don't try to force you to use a particular framework for something and let you choose one yourself. Just don't listen if the documentation tells you something is discouraged if you think it makes more sense for your projects.

Comment: But as I'm new to Play (or anything else), Isn't it better for me to follow the guidelines and recommendations of its creators?

Comment: Yes of course, you should generally follow the guidelines. Some things in the default setup just aren't necessarily the best solution for _every_ situation. DI is a good example. What I tried to say is that it's good to also look for alternatives to the tools and frameworks recommended in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the majority of samples does not use Dependency Injection. But since the 2.1 version, it is possible to inject the controllers, and their dependencies.

For the dependency injection, check the [doc](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/documentation/manual/scalaGuide/advanced/ScalaDependencyInjection.md) and also, [how to unit test](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaTest) (last paragraph).

But since there are many static calls, you could end up with some static reference somewhere and you'll not be able to unit test your code.

But I think Play is a great framework, the team is modularizing more and more the framework, so that it will be better and better regarding SOLID principles.

Comment: So is Play ready for production now? Can I use it in production or I should wait until it gets more mature?

Comment: Yes, Play is ready for production; for instance, it is used by [Linked In](http://engineering.linkedin.com/play/play-framework-linkedin).